# Json data is not getting stored in Sqlite

Tags: android, json, sqlite

I am using Recyclerview ,Here is Json file the insert query written in Json array though the json data is not stored in SQLite.When we destroy the app and again restart it will only show 
blank rows and again press a button and it will show json data aftr emptyrow ie:after destroy data gets lost.Do help me thank you

```
public class Recyclerview extends AppCompatActivity {
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
CustomAdapter cu;

ArrayList<Employee> arr, arr1;
Toolbar toolbar;

TextView t1, t2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.recyclerview);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar1);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    final RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);
    rv.setHasFixedSize(true);

    arr = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    arr = InitializeData();

    final LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(Recyclerview.this);
    rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
    rv.setHasFixedSize(true);

    cu = new CustomAdapter(Recyclerview.this, arr);

    rv.setAdapter(cu);

    registerForContextMenu(rv);
    final bank ban = new bank(Recyclerview.this);
    ImageButton refresh = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.refresh);

    refresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Toast.makeText(Recyclerview.this, "ok", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (isNetworkAvailable()) {

                String url = ConstantValues.BASE_URL;
                RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                        .add("key1", "value1")
                        .add("key2", "value2")
                        .add("key3", "value3")
                        .build();

                try {
                    post(url, formBody, new Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                            Log.e("JSONDemo", "IOException", e);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(final Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
                            String JSON = response.body().string();
                            Log.e("res", " " + JSON);
                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(JSON);

                                JSONArray resultarr = jsonObj.getJSONArray("result");
                                final JSONArray resultarr1 = jsonObj.getJSONArray("result1");

                                ban.OpenDB();
                                ban.OpenDB();
                                for (int i = 0; i < resultarr1.length(); i++) {

                                    Employee emp = new Employee();
                                    JSONObject result1obj = resultarr1.getJSONObject(i);
                                    String result1Id = result1obj.getString(ConstantValues.Bank_ID);
                                    String result1NAME = result1obj.getString(ConstantValues.Bank_NAME);
                                    Log.e("result", " " + result1Id);
                                    Log.e("result", " " + result1NAME);
                                    emp.setId(result1obj.getString(ConstantValues.Bank_ID));
                                    emp.setName(result1obj.getString(ConstantValues.Bank_NAME));
                                    arr.add(emp);
                                    long l = 0;
                                    l=ban.InsertQryForTabEmpData(ConstantValues.Bank_ID,ConstantValues.Bank_NAME);



                                }
                                ban.CloseDB();


                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                                                                    cu.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    }
                                });
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Log.e("JSONDemo", "onResponse", e);
                            }

                        }
                    });

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("JSONDemo", "Post Exception", e);
                }

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(Recyclerview.this, "Internet not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


        }
    });


}

private ArrayList<Employee> InitializeData() {
    ArrayList<Employee> arr_emp = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    bank ban = new bank(Recyclerview.this);
    long l = 0;
    ban.OpenDB();
    arr_emp = ban.AllSelectQryForTabEmpData1();
    ban.CloseDB();
    return arr_emp;
}


private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
            = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}


private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

Call post(String url, RequestBody formBody, Callback callback) throws IOException {

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .post(formBody)
            .build();

    Call call = client.newCall(request);
    call.enqueue(callback);
    return call;
}
}
```

It is the query of all SQLite:

```
public class bank {

private Context context;
private SQLiteDatabase SQLiteDb;

public bank(Context context){
    this.context=context;
}


public static class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, ConstantValues.DBName, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(" create table if not exists " + ConstantValues.TabEmpData+"("
                + ConstantValues.Bank_ID + " text, "
                + ConstantValues.Bank_NAME  + " text )");




    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        db.execSQL(" create table if not exists " + ConstantValues.TabEmpData+"("
                + ConstantValues.Bank_ID + " text, "
                + ConstantValues.Bank_NAME  + " text )");



    }
}

public void OpenDB() {

    SQLiteDb = new DBHelper(context).getWritableDatabase();
}

public void CloseDB() {
    if (SQLiteDb.isOpen()) {
        SQLiteDb.close();
    }
}

public long InsertQryForTabEmpData(String ID, String NAME) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(ConstantValues.Bank_ID, ID);
    cv.put(ConstantValues.Bank_NAME, NAME);


    long l = SQLiteDb.insert(ConstantValues.TabEmpData, null, cv);
    return l;
}

public long UpdateQryForTabEmpData(String ID
        , String NAME
) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(ConstantValues.Bank_ID, ID);
    cv.put(ConstantValues.Bank_NAME, NAME);

    long l = SQLiteDb.update(ConstantValues.TabEmpData, cv, ConstantValues.Bank_ID+ "=" + ID, null);
    return l;
}

public long DeleteQryForTabEmpData(String ID) {
    long l = SQLiteDb.delete(ConstantValues.TabEmpData, ConstantValues.Bank_ID+ "=" + ID, null);

    return l;
}

public ArrayList SelectQryForTabEmpData(String ID) {
    ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList();

    String[] arg = {
            "ID"
            , "NAME"

    };

    String selection = "  ID=  " + ID;
    String QRY = " SELECT ID,NAME FROM  TabEmpData WHERE  ID =  " + ID;// +" AND EmpFName = 'test' grup by empid,fname,lastname  having Empsalary > = 2000 order by fname asc,salry desc limit 100";
    Cursor cursor = SQLiteDb.rawQuery(QRY, null);//
    SQLiteDb.query(ConstantValues.TabEmpData, arg, selection, null, null, null, null, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        data.add(0, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ConstantValues.Bank_ID)));
        data.add(1, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ConstantValues.Bank_NAME)));

    }
    cursor.close();
    return data;
}

public ArrayList AllSelectQryForTabEmpData1() {
    ArrayList<Employee> data = new ArrayList();


    Cursor cursor = SQLiteDb.query(ConstantValues.TabEmpData, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ConstantValues.Bank_ID));
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ConstantValues.Bank_NAME));


        data.add(new Employee(id, name));


    }
    cursor.close();
    return data;
}



}
```

Its my Custom Adapter:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.EmpDataViewHolder> {
    final bank ban = new bank(CustomAdapter.this.context);
    private ArrayList<Employee> arr,filterlist;
    private Context context;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Employee> arr) {
        this.arr=arr;
        this.context=context;

        Toast.makeText(context,""+arr.size(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



    }

    @Override
    public EmpDataViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.cardview, parent, false);
        EmpDataViewHolder edvh = new EmpDataViewHolder(v);
        return edvh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(EmpDataViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Employee emp=arr.get(position) ;

        holder.id.setText(emp.getId());
        holder.name.setText(emp.getName());

        holder.cv.setTag(R.string.KeyForCV,position);




    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

            return arr.size();



    }

    public class EmpDataViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {

        CardView cv;
        TextView id;
        TextView name;


        public EmpDataViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cv= (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
            id= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.id);
            name= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        }
    }
}
```

Do help me i want to get rid out of this problem thank you in advance

Comment: post ur json file format

Comment: Seems to be a fair amount of code here. Could you try to make a [mcve]?

Comment: means xml file? @R.K

Comment: Your json Response.

Comment: ok I am Posting the whole Code here do help me...

Comment: Are you receving data from your json file?.. try using Log and check..

Comment: yes i receive my data but when it destroys it becomes invisible or let we say the data is gone again click on button json data again recerived @R.K

Comment: l=ban.InsertQryForTabEmpData(result1Id ,result1NAME );   change this in Recyclerview  Class

Comment: l=ban.InsertQryForTabEmpData(result1Id,result1NAME); same error i had tried this before too bt gave same error

Comment: yeah i got it was a simple mistake in getter and setter thank you all...